# SQL Server SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, select

I need a query that returns rows from table A if value X in table A is not the same as the sum of value Y from corresponding row(s) in table B. The issue is that there may or may not be rows in table B that correspond to the rows in table A, but if there no rows in table B, then the rows from table A should still be returned (because there is not a matching value in table B.) So it is like a LEFT OUTER join scenario, but the extra complication of having a comparison as an additional selection criteria.

I have a query that does the opposite, ie. returns rows if the value in table A is the same as the value of row(s) in table B, but sadly this isn't what I need!

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.bdate
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = TableA.id
WHERE TableA.select_field = 408214
AND TableA.planned_volume = 
(select sum(actual_volume)
 from 
 TableB 
 where TableB.id = TableA.id)
ORDER BY TableA.id
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample query only projects attributes from TableA, so I assume TableB is only being using for existential quantification. Correct?

Comment: "but if there no rows in table B" -- do you mean a) TableB is the empty set (literal interpretation), b) no matching rows using common `id` attribute, c) no matching rows using matching `id` and 'sum of Y' expression, d) something else?

Comment: to answer your first question ... that's right - the fields to be returned just come from TableA, but the qualification depends on the sum of actual_value on rows in tableB being not equal to the planned_value field on TableA

Comment: and your second point ... b) because TableB contains 'actual_volumes' which may or may not exist for a 'planned_volume' that has been added to TableA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH TotalVolumes
     AS 
     (
      SELECT id, SUM(actual_volume) AS total_volume
        FROM TableB 
       GROUP 
          BY id
     )
SELECT id, bdate, planned_volume 
  FROM TableA
EXCEPT 
SELECT A.id, A.bdate, T.total_volume
  FROM TableA AS A 
       JOIN TotalVolumes AS T 
          ON A.id = T.id;
```

Comment: onedaywhen, you've cracked it, but now I need to add something to produce the first row returned, like:- SELECT -1 AS Batch_Id, '{SELECT}' AS Batch_Date
UNION and SELECT ... UNION dont seem to go with WITH :-(

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.bdate
FROM TableA
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT Id, SUM(actual_volume) AS b_volume
        FROM TableB 
        GROUP BY Id
    ) AS TableBGrouping
        ON TableBGrouping.Id= TableA.Id AND TableA.planned_volume <> b_volume
ORDER BY TableA.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.bdate
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = TableA.id
AND TableA.planned_volume <> 
(select sum(actual_volume)
 from 
 TableB 
 where TableB.id = TableA.id)
ORDER BY TableA.id
```

Comment: No, doesnt work because if there is a row in TableA but nothing in TableB, then nothing is returned

Comment: Just slightly changed it, try again.

Comment: Sorry, too subtle for me, but I already tried using <>, but it doesn't return what I need